# Unable to upgrade r-base-core package to backports in Debian

Tags: r, debian, apt, backport

I am trying to upgrade `r-base-core` from version 3.1.1-1 in Debian Jessie to version 3.3.2-1 in jessie-backports.  My setup:

```
$ apt-cache policy r-base-core
r-base-core:
  Installed: 3.1.1-1+deb8u1
  Candidate: 3.1.1-1+deb8u1
  Version table:
     3.3.3-1~jessiecran.0 0
        500 http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/debian/ jessie-cran3/ Packages
     3.3.2-1~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.1.1-1+deb8u1 0
       1000 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
       1000 http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.1.1-1+b2 0
        900 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        900 http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        900 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
```

When I execute `sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install r-base-core`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r-base-core is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 205 not upgraded.
```

Why doesn't it see the `jessie-backports`version as being newer?  How do I debug this?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display shows the `***` for the selected variant.  Below is the all-important *score* of a 1000 which is higher than the alternatives of 100 and 500, respectively, for the higher versions.

This is a feature called apt-pinning.  You need to adjust the ranking you give the different repos.  *At equal or lower score*, the upgrade to a higher version happens as you would expect.

Comment: So, I might increase the pin-priority of jessie-backports to 1001 in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`?

Comment: Right. Or to 1100 to stay with round numbers, or there may be a command to temporarily override the default which is currently in your way.  There ought to be a number of decent tutorial out there on this.

Comment: Actually ... this is one-off because we usually do not have R builds in debian-security which has a well deserved higher priority.  Maybe just temporarily override, then put the packages on hold (until 3.4.0 comes out in three weeks) and put the priority back for good security practice. (And the actual security issue is benign, a `snprintf()` change for pdf device paths.)

Comment: Thanks for all the information.  It's good to know how/why these things change around!